# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fluid' of null

Tags: javascript, gatsby, contentful

I am trying to get images from contentful data to gatsby site. I can retrieve text contents.

I went through the `gatsby-image` plugin documentation. it looks fine.

```
const getBlogList = graphql`
{
  blogs: allContentfulBlog {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        image {
          fluid(maxWidth:250) {
            ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG
          }        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

<StaticQuery 
      query={getBlogList} 
      render={ data => {
      return({data.blogs.edges.map(({node})=>{
      return(<div><Img fluid={node.image.fluid} /></div>)
          }) 
        }
       )
      }} />
```

I could not find where I went wrong. I got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fluid' of null.

Comment: check out this issue - https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9423

Comment: I had the same issue, it was because the original file name of the uploaded image contained a dot and a question mark. Uploading a file with a decent name to Contentful did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

When you get the read property of null error it's means that the parent property is null. Maybe some node hasn't any image property, so when you try to read the fluid of null you got the error. 
Try to check for existence of image in node on your map function before using it to reach the fluid property.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this inside JSX to check the existence of a value:

```
{node.image && (         //Check with console.log what value node.image?
   <div><Img fluid={node.image.fluid} />  //renders if value present
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for commenting on an old question. I do have a possible answer, though.
I was getting this same (or at least a seemingly quite similar) error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fluid')`

In my case, I didn't have the image files I needed in the branch I was working from. I simply brought the images over to my content/images folder in my working branch. My page built after this simple fix.

I hope that this helps someone and isn't out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Mehdi is right. I had the same issue but when I realized I forgot to put the images from Contentful dashboard and set all images from there, the problem was solved. The error is trying to tell you you haven't yet set all the images from Contentful dashboard. That's why parent property is null.